# Maven installation failure on Yosemite: No compiler is provided in this environment

Tags: java, maven, osx-yosemite

I think problem is mvn don't find java or something like that.

If I run java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Maven:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T13:57:37+02:00)
Maven home: /Users/rubenortiz/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.003 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-03T13:09:44+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/302M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :core
```

Answer (score 3):

try javac -version...

because 'Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK'... Looks like there is no compiler.

/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home is where java is ran from... And does not link to a JDK but to an internet plugin

Maybe install JDK or change JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 2):

The problem is pretty straightforward.  Your java version query reports a JRE. As the maven error states it needs the JDK. Install the JDK and adjust the environment variable accordingly.